# How to get parameters from DialogFlow Event

Tags: python, json, dialogflow-es

I have a list which triggers an event but I'm not sure how to go about getting the parameters from the event.

[image: This is what the history looks like]

[image: and this is the intent the event triggers]

I'm using Python for the webhook fulfillment and the [flask-assistant](https://github.com/treethought/flask-assistant) library. This is my code:

```
        resp = ask("Here are the results")
        mylist = resp.build_list("Which one?")
        i=0
        for names in fullName:
            mylist.add_item(title=names,
                key=names,
                img_url="",
                description=email[i],
                synonyms=synons[i]) 
            i=i+1       
        return mylist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dialogflow includes the event (`actions_intent_OPTION`) as a context with the key as the selected option. In the raw request it looks something like this:

```
"contexts": [
      {
        "name": "actions_intent_option",
        "parameters": {
          "OPTION": "YOUR_KEY_HERE"
        },
        "lifespan": 0
      }
]
```

With flask-assistant you can read the value from the [`context_manager`](http://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contexts.html#context-manager) (which contains all contexts in the active session):

```
from flask_assistant import context_manager

selected_option = context_manager.get('actions_intent_option').get('OPTION')
```

The key can be whatever you find most useful, it will not be shown to the user. Typically you would use some kind of id that uniquely identifies your list items.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.